# redirecting to diffrent routes in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have this route in flask :

```
@app.route("/welcome/<string:book_isbn>",methods=["GET", "POST"])
def book(book_isbn):
```

and i have an html file , which has the following link :

```
<a href="{{ url_for('welcome',book_isbn=book.isbn)}}">
```

where book.isbn is a variable that i passed earlier when rendering this html file .

when clicking on the link iam hoping to achieve that it will go to the route i mentioned

but instead it goes to this route :

```
@app.route("/welcome",methods=['GET','POST'])
def welcome():
```

and in the web browser on top i can see the route welcome?book_isbn=xxxxxx (x is just some number)

so i think the '?' is the problem, but i cant wrap my head around on whats causing it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might've checked but... Did you confirm that `book.isbn` is a `string`?

The `?` appears when the `url_for` function has parameters that do not match with the existing routes, so there is a problem with that `<string:book_isbn>`. Docs [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for)

You can try with one of the following lines:

```py
type(book.isbn) # Should return "str"
isinstance(book.isbn, str) # Should return True
```

## Edit

Try to route both routes into a single one with an optional parameter:

```py
@app.route("/welcome",methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route("/welcome/<string:book_isbn>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def book(book_isbn=None):
    if book_isbn:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Actually this book.isbn is read from an psql database . in the database the isbn is varchar , but i checked and found out  that varchar is equivelent to string . or do you think i need to convert it ?

Comment: Try to cast it to string, I dont know how psql works with that, but it may have its own types. A simple `str(returned_value_from_psqldb)` may solve it.

Comment: well , it didnt help